# How to call ajax from select event of autocomplete jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

When user enter a key/letter the autocompleter ll show the possible keys if user select a key from list it ll add to input box but here I want, when user select an item from list, the item send to server via ajax and show corresponding data to auto list

```
.autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(request, response) {
        console.log(response);
        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            title_json_data, extractLast(request.term)));//last element
        },
        focus: function() {
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            terms.pop();
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            //**here i want to call ajax function 
            //and server requet add to auto list box**
            return false;
        }
    });
```

ie when use select an item from list just send to server and server replied data add to list box 
thanks in advance

Comment: where are you doing the ajax request, what list box?

Comment: Where is the problem then? Can not make the ajax hit?